# Dependanat Drop down is not working when it has only one value in yii framework

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii

I am using dependant dropdownlist for get value for subject dropdown when select value from 'Grade' dropdown. It is working fine. But the problem is when there are only one value in grade dropdown the subject dropdown is not updated.

this is my code:-

Grade DropDown----------
($data is consist of grade)

```
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('myDropDown1','',$data,array( 
              'id'=>'gr', 
              'empty' => '(Select Grade)',
              'style'=>'width:200px',   
              'ajax' =>
              array(
              'type'=>'POST', //request type
              'url'=>CController::createUrl('sub'), //action to call
              'update'=>'#cls', // which HTML element to update
             )
             )); ?>
```

Subject Dropdown (which depend on grade dropdown)------------

```
            <?php echo CHtml::label('Subject',''); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('myDropDown3','',array(),array(
            'id'=>'sub',
            'prompt'=> 'Please select a class', 'style'=>'width:150px',
           'style'=>'width:200px',
            )); ?>
            <?php //echo $form->error($model,'sub_id'); ?>
```

In controller-------------------

```
    public function actionClass()
    {
     $grd = $_POST['myDropDown1']; 
     $c_id = TbClass::model()->findAll('id=:id',
                    array(':id'=>$grd,));
     $data3 = CHtml::listData($c_id,'id','grade');
     $grd2 = array_shift($data3);

     $sub1 = TbClass::model()->findAll('grade=:grade',
        array(
        ':grade'=>$grd2,
         )); 
     $data4 = CHtml::listData($sub1,'id','class');

     foreach($data4 as $value=>$name)
     {
      echo CHtml::tag('option',
               array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
     }
```

}

This code is working fine. Problem is when grade has only one value in the dropdown , cannot update the subject dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in array_shift,

have you checked the value of $grd2 ?